# iPad Calculator App Portrait Only?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am making a calculator app for the iPad. I would like to know if it would be acceptable to most users (the golden 80% rule) for the calculator to be locked in portrait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not - many cases for the iPad hold it elevated in landscape, so a user with the screen raised would not be able to use your calculator. I can't provide figures, but would suggest that looking at the most popular calculator apps should give you some indication about which designs are succeeding and failing on the app store.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get to completely rejigger my entire app and learn auto layout! (Good thing)

Comment: :D My work here is done ;)